# animationend not working in recursive function

Tags: javascript, css

I have the function below which I want to use to loop through each id, stored in an array, that points to dynamic HTML elements I added to a div. Then, I want to change the CSS class and add an animationend event listener. It all works except I've noticed that the event is firing before the animation is complete. What ends up happening is that all of the elements in the array animate at once. I want each element to animation in succession. I've been playing around with the code and looking online for answers but I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Javascript code:

```
        function moveLines(count){
            if(count<=introLinesBlurEls.length){
                thisMoveLine = document.getElementById(introLinesBlurEls[count]);
                thisMoveLine.className = 'introImgBlurAnimate';
                count++;
                thisMoveLine.addEventListener('animationend', moveLines(count), false);
            }else{
                alert('Hey. I am done.');
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think if you need to pass parameters to the listener function you need to wrap it in an anonymous function. `thisMoveLine.addEventListener('animationend', function(){moveLines(count)}, false);`

Comment: Oh, really? Okay. I'll try that. But, the thing is, I know it's calling the function every time. It does animate all the elements in my array. It's just doing them all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your handler, where you want to assign it.

```
thisMoveLine.addEventListener('animationend', moveLines(count), false);
```

This is executing moveLines(). You need to defer the execution of moveLines until the event occurs. to do this you need to create a closure so you can bind the count argument.

```
thisMoveLine.addEventListener('animationend', moveLines.bind(this, count), false);
```

you could use .bind() or wrap it in a function to preserve the scope

```
thisMoveLine.addEventListener('animationend', function(){ moveLines(count); }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there might be different names for animation events in different browsers: `webkitAnimationEnd`, `animationend`, `MSAnimationEnd`, e.g. for me in chrome only `webkitAnimationEnd` works correctly. So its better to  bind handlers for all of them (you may create single function for this).

Also in order to pass `count` parameter to event handler correctly you should either use anonymous function, or move count variable to global scope and call `moveLines` without parameters.

When you put this 'moveLines(count)' as a second argument for addEventListener, you actually immediately invoke `moveLines` function and pass its result to addEventListener, rather then passing function itself.

see working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/0oszt1xg/1/)